# Partial start date with end date output views

Tags: views, 8, datetime

I'm using views to output a list of nodes with dates. Some node dates have both a start and end date inserted.

If both a start and end date exists, i would like the date to be outputted only taking the day from the start date.

Current: 9 January 2018 - 10 January 2018

Desired: 9 - 10 January 2018

I've tried using a custom field and rewriting the results in views, but this doesn't work. I've also looked in the pre_render and preprocess functions and only see the start date.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are the start and end dates separate fields, or is this a single daterange field?

Comment: It's a single date range field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved this issue using the compact daterange module, and using one of the committed patches.

https://www.drupal.org/project/daterange_compact

Answer (score 1):

There is a possibility to do it without an extra module

- Add a field in views for the start date and use the custom formatter with `j` as the custom format. This will output the date without month or year.
- Add a field for end date and format this date as you wish.
- `Rewrite Results` of end date field (or add a custom field) and put the appropriate token replacements

  > {{ field_start_date }} - {{ field_end_date }}

**Note:** this solution cannot handle properly dates spanning 2 or more months